# How to activate the keybindings in the jframe or jtabbedpane if the focus is not gained?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener, jtabbedpane

I have this code in my jTabbedPane1

```
private void jTabbedPane1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
    int t,getkey = evt.getKeyCode();
    if(KeyEvent.VK_F9 == getkey)
    {
        if(t == 0)
        {
            jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(1);
            jTabbedPane1.requestFocusInWindow();
            t = t + 1;
        }
        else if(t == 1)
        {
            jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(0);
            jTabbedPane1.requestFocusInWindow();
            t = t - 1;
        }
    }
 }
```

but when the focus is lost in the jtabbedpane this code and keybindings are useless. 
How can I trigger this keypressed event inside the jframe without gaining the focus of the jtabbedpane?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can have a thread which continuously sets the focus to the frame you are attempting to have a key listener running in. Otherwise, I think it is impossible if the frame does not have the focus.

What you are attempting to do would in a sense be considered a system-wide key-listener. This can be implemented in C/C++ or even Python.

If you must use java, then you are going to have to check out native libraries and the usage of the "native" keyword in java. Natives in java provide the JVM with the ability to integrate native code implementations, 
i.e) C/C++